# how to create our own O(1) substring function in java as it was in jdk 6.

Tags: java, string, algorithm

How to create our own O(1) substring function in java as it was in jdk 6. If there is any method to use substring() of jdk 6 on advanced versions of jdk ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The O(1) `substring` was because the underlying character array of the string could be *shared* between objects. Hence `substring` simply required creating an object with a pointer to the original string along with an offset and length. There was no copying of the actual data itself, which had the annoying effect that taking a small substring of a huge string, then deleting the huge one, didn't actually free up memory. This lead to code such as:

```
String newstr = new String(oldStr.substring(5,9));
```

rather than the more sensible-looking:

```
String newstr = oldStr.substring(5,9);
```

Since strings no longer share data (Update 6 of Java 7 is where I think this happened), that's not possible so, if you want to get back that O(1) performance, you'll basically have to construct your *own* string class to do it.

Just be aware that you may be worrying about something that's not so important. Unless your strings are *very* large, the extra cost (in space and time) of copying the data for them may be inconsequential.

And the extra effort in converting your `O1String` into `String` for every function that needs the latter, as well as the less than perfect integration with literal strings, may well make it even worse.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can view how it was implimented in Java 6

[Open JDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.substring%28int%29)